# Is there a way to check if some value is IN request.session.name?

Tags: python, django, templates, session, jinja2

Can anybody clarify, please?
I got a Cart object in request.session
I want to check **if request.session.cart CONTAINS item.id as a key** *from template*

```
{% if game.id in request.session.cart %}
```

I know that game.id is FOR SURE in that cart object, but template doesn't react on that.
I HAVE a context processor added

UPDATE:

### SETTINGS.PY

```
        'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            'order.context_processors.cart',
        ],
```

### Template and session data

game.id is seen on the picture (actual value is not seen but it is the same as in cart) and below there is cart content
[template and session data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFKnf.png)`enter code here`

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an issue with your template. Can you post the code that you are __sure__ is populating the session and the `game` context variable?

Comment: Can you add a snippet of what exactly `request.session.cart` will contain? Also you say "I HAVE a context processor added" it would be better in that case to _show_ the context processor and also show the `context_processors` part of the `TEMPLATES` setting

Comment: @IainShelvington . Thanks for reply !
I added a snippet with request.session.cart content. Game.id is the same. BTW, when i try to display {{ game.id }} and {{ request.session.cart }} separately   - I got 
`7657956b-a9f4-4e67-973d-6e2a567d2f77`
**and**
`{&#x27;7657956b-a9f4-4e67-973d-6e2a567d2f77&#x27;: {&#x27;item_price&#x27;: 55.0, &#x27;qty&#x27;: 1}}
`

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Thanks for reply!
I added a snippet with request.session.cart content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, everybody whom it might concern. The problem was that I had game.id value of UUID. The value passed to **cart** was a string. They "looked" the same, but types were different.
I used `{{ game.id|slugify }}` to convert UUID to string. That's it